# How to get the file with the latest yymm in a Directory?

Tags: python-3.x

There are several files in a directory which contains digit and non-digits as well. Lets say abc1710.csv, xyz1709.txt, abc1708.txt, abc.txt, xyz.csv.
I want to extract only the latest YYMM from the fileName.

```
FileNames = (next(os.walk('C:\\Python34\\PyScript'))[2])

def check_file_name(f):
    try:
        digits = f[-4:]
        if len(digits) != 4:
            return False
        int(f[-4:])
    except:
        return False
    return True
# first filter out bad file names:
good_filenames = [x for x in FileNames if check_file_name(x)]

# now run the code on "good names" only:
fileName=(max(good_filenames))
value=(fileName[-4:])
result = re.sub(r'[a-z]+', '', fileName)
print(result)
```

Comment: Where do you have problems?

Comment: It's giving an error:
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `check_file_name` assumes the extension is trimmed already, but you give it the entire file name. It should be fixed by doing

```
good_filenames = [x for x in FileNames if check_file_name(x[:-4])]
```

In addition, if you want to get the largest number, you also have to make your comparison on the numbers, not on the filenames:

```
fileName=max(good_filenames, key=lambda x: int(x[-8:-4]))
```

Future suggestions:

- Don't use CamelCase, except on class names
- There's no need to put a parenthesis around function calls (e.g. `(max(good_filenames))`)

Comment: I tried the replacing the line but it is taking 6 characters including "." of the file name.

Comment: Its not giving the right output. I have these list of files but I am getting 1709 as output.. :(
abc1708.fmt, abc1710.txt, pqr-1707.fmt, xyz1709.txt

Comment: That's because you get the "largest" element in a sequence of strings. Will update my answer accordingly